# Handling errors while using unmanaged code in a managed one ( C++, C, C++/CLI, C#)

Tags: c#, c++, exception

I am using a badly written 3rd party (C/C++) Api. I used it from managed code( C++/ CLI). Get sometimes "access violation errors". And this crash whole application. I know i can not handle those errors[  what can i do if a pointer acess to illegal memory location etc].

But I do not want my application crash as a whole. At least if there is a real problem, my application gracefully should say "OK.I can not do my job.BYE. " :-) then it least execute some alternative scenarious and finally close itself.

But there seems to be no way, to catch( may be wrong term, the rigth word may be to be informed about) access violation and similiar errors.Is there a way to be informed  about those errors. So i can execute my alternative scenarious.

PS: Standard Exception handling does not solve this.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace System;

using namespace std;


static void ThrowingManagedException()
{

    throw gcnew ArgumentException("For no good reason");

}

static void ThrowingNativeException()
{

    throw std::exception("For no good reason");



}

static void SomeBadThingsHappen()
{

    short a[1]; 

    a[0]=1;

    a[2]= 2; // SomeOne make stupid mistake

}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Test Exceptions");

    try 
    {

        SomeBadThingsHappen();
         //ThrowingNativeException();         
         //ThrowingManagedException();
    }


    catch(Exception^ e)
    {
        Console::WriteLine("Something awful happened: "+ e);
    }


    Console::WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
    Console::Read();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I'm correct, won't P/Invoke "convert" unmanaged errors into managed exceptions that you can catch?

Comment: @SimpleCoder: Yes, but it won't undo the damage caused by wild pointers.

Comment: Its really simple.  If you have bad pointers there is no really good way of handling that problem.  Say the library was a program itself, all that would happen is the program would crash, this is similar to the "OutOfMemoryException" where there simply is no way to recover from it.

Comment: @Ramhound I do not want to recover anything. I just want to able to know it.If "OutOfMemoryException" occured you can know it (can log it) and may be do nothing. But i can not cath(or to be informed gracefully) about those errors.[ so no logging about errors]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure that the problems are bugs in the library, and not a result of you passing in bad arguments, then your most robust option is inter-process communication with a hosting process that loads the library.  That way your OS process separation keeps the library from bringing down your application.

You can try to catch access violations in-process, using SEH, but if the library writes to wild pointers and not simple null pointers, then the process won't survive even with an exception handler.

Your example will not cause an access violation, it's a buffer overrun of a buffer on the stack, so the adjacent memory location contains some other valid data which gets stomped on.

Comment: Acess violation is just an example.Geneally i mean errors that are not cath up by standard exception handling.